# Unexpected behaviour from auth('api')->user() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

so i've come across what looks like a really peculiar issue. I had been using auth('api')->user() to get the user collection in a model method used by various controllers. For an API setup as a public route with api middleware its controller was using this model method and the code was only sporadically working.

I'll paste two versions of code below.

This version would sometimes return null for $user even if the user was logged in.

```
    if(Auth::user()){
        $user = Auth::user();
    }elseif(auth('api')->user()){
        $user = auth('api')->user();
    }else{
        $user = null;
    }
```

The second version of code seems to always return the user collection for $user when the user is logged in.

```
    $apiUser = auth('api')->user();

    if(Auth::user()){
        $user = Auth::user();
    }elseif(auth('api')->user()){
        $user = auth('api')->user();
    }else{
        $user = null;
    }
```

I cannot for the life of me understand why the second version would work properly and the first wouldn't. I only stumbled accross that it worked whilst trying to debug the code. Can anyone try and explain!

Comment: The only way to ensure $user object always exists in this case is to use the `auth:api` on your route.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Auth::check()` to check if user logged in or not.
So you code will look like:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
   $user = Auth::user();
}
```